# Questions related to IntelliJ IDEA deployment to Tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat, intellij-idea, deployment

I have one question related to SpringMVC web application with IntelliJ IDEA and  deploying to Tomcat.

First installed Tomcat successfully and can connected to localhost:8080.

But when I configured Tomcat in IDEA and deployed to Tomcat.
Got the output as below:

```
17:01:19|WARN |SQL Error: 1045, SQLState: 28000
17:01:19|ERROR|Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
17:01:19|WARN |Could not obtain connection metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
```

It seems that mysql can't be connected.
I tried to connect it in the terminal and got success.

I also got the success information as below:

```
17:01:29|INFO |Found JSP 2.1 ExpressionFactory
17:01:29|INFO |Initializing Tiles2 application context. . .
17:01:29|INFO |Finished initializing Tiles2 application context.
17:01:29|INFO |Initializing Tiles2 container. . .
17:01:29|INFO |Tiles2 container initialized
17:01:29|INFO |Publishing TilesContext for context: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory$SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext
17:01:29|INFO |FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 2134 ms
[2016-12-20 05:01:29,441] Artifact WebMail:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-12-20 05:01:29,443] Artifact WebMail:war exploded: Deploy took 17,785 milliseconds
```

But "localhost:8080" is not accessible after the deployment.

Is the deployment successful or not?

Comment: Did you connect with the same user from command line? You can confirm by creating a specific mysql user and trying with that user (make sure they have the correct permissions).

Comment: What user credentials are set up in tomcat installation `conf/tomcat-users.xml` ?

Comment: Hi Boris
Yes i connect with the same user from command line root@localhost

Comment: The users configuration is as below

Comment: <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="123456" roles="manager-gui"/>

Comment: I can get the same error when trying to Run and Debug tomcat from IDEA.

Comment: The error happened with the information as 
11:45:11|INFO |building session factory
11:45:12|INFO |Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
11:45:12|INFO |Running hbm2ddl schema update
11:45:12|INFO |fetching database metadata
11:45:12|WARN |SQL Error: 1045, SQLState: 28000
11:45:12|ERROR|Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
11:45:12|ERROR|could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Seems that the error is with the hbm2ddl update

Comment: Got resolved now. Should modify the datasource login information in the webapps folder.